# Angular Unit Testing : How to run a basic Test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

Am new on angular unit testing.

I wanna implement a first running test so i developed this :

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('first test', () => {
    expect('1').toBe('1');
  });
});
```

Like you see my first test is to assert that "1" is "1" , i don't know why i'm facing a problem of getting it successfull , since it throws me such an error :

```
Error: Template parse errors:   Can't bind to 'min' since it isn't a known property of 'dx-progress-bar'.
    1. If 'dx-progress-bar' is an Angular component and it has 'min' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'dx-progress-bar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
        width="100%"
        [class.complete]="progressBar.value == maxValue"
        [ERROR ->][min]="0"
        [max]="maxValue"
        [statusFormat]="wordProgression"    "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@15:4
```

It's true that i'm using DevExtreme widgets in my app component , but i haven't even tried to test it. i'm just starting by evident test cases.

I need to know how should i fix it?

**Suggestions ??**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include all things that need to compile your component in your `TestBed.configureTestingModule`:

```
// import { DevExtremeModule } from 'devextreme-angular';
import { DxProgressBarModule } from 'devextreme-angular/ui/progress-bar';


TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    DxProgressBarModule,
    // or DevExtremeModule
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
}).compileComponents();
```

Comment: Basically, what yurzui intented to say was that you need to actually recreate a dynamic module to test your component. The reason is because everything is linked with dependency injection with the Angular stuff, and you must recreate a module with `TestBed.configureTestingModule()` to provide the minimum required for your component to compile.
If you need services / pipes, or anything like that, do not forget to `stub` your classes to use them as mocks.

Comment: @AlexBeugnet , thanks a lot for those informations , thus i wanna know how can i stub / mock my services ??

Comment: Something like `{ provide: MyService, useClass: MyServiceMock }`

Comment: Exactly, you declare your Class which should override the existing one and use mock data instead of HTTP calls. See this link for a full example : https://angular.io/guide/testing#test-a-component-with-a-dependency

Comment: The anchor in the last link isn't very precise so here is the new one : https://angular.io/guide/testing#provide-service-test-doubles